How to do a conditional selection between 2 tables to update a view
I have a tableau dashboard connected to a view. The data to this view is coming from 2 identical tables that gets refreshed with same data but during different time instance.
I need the data in the view to be latest all the time. Both tables have a date column where all the values are same that is the time it got refreshed.
Eg when table1 get refreshed with latest data the view should take data from table1
When table1 and table2 has same data take data from table1
When table2 has latest data take data from table2.
Both the tables are from a data warehouse with huge volume of data. So doing an union and filtering by date is not cost effective. Is there a way to do a if else condition to perform while selecting between 2 tables.
I tried doing union and filtering by latest date. Even though it worked it has affected the performance.
Solution I found is
select *
from (
    select * from table1
    union
    select * from table2
)
where date in (
    select max(date)
    from (
        select * from table1
        union
        select * from table2
    )
)


And you need to be more specific about your question, it needs to a single, clear, specific issue - as it stands its too general and vague to be able to answer.

I want to know if a concept is available in SQL to do this kind of operations efficiently

Almost all SQL operations are totally dependent on the platform you are using... hence you need to tag a single RDBMS (You still have 2, MySQL & SQL Server). And SQL doesn't typically deal with generic concepts, if you are having performance issues you need to investigate why using the execution plan. A query is only a description of the data you want, its not an instruction on how the database should retrieve that data - hence to solve a performance issue you investigate what the database engine was doing because without knowing that you can't improve your query.

i dunno tableau, but your load process or some other process can check which table is the latest by doing select top 1 somedate and either set some synonym to point to correct table

All operations can be done effectively, but I don't even understand what you want to accomplish from a vague text description. If you can provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results I think you will find that people can understand that much better.

It's not related to tableau. It's just that this view is source of a tableau dashboard. @Dalek the requirement is for me to know if a parallel concept is available other than using a union operations. Solution I found is select * from (select * from table1 union select * from table2) where date in (select max(date) from (select * from table1 union select * from table2))

The query you have posted has syntax errors. And from a speed perspective union all is faster than union if you are using SQL Server - but you haven't told us which RDBMS you are using

I'm using bigquery as underlying database. I cannot use union All because there will be duplicates when both tables have same data

Optimizations will depends on tables partitions and clusters. The tables has partitions or clusters? In what columns? If the contents are equal, there is a reason to both process not write to same table?

I am not aware of a way to do what you want. However, you may be able to use a materialized view (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create) by UNION ALLing the 2 tables in a common table expression into a single table/CTE, then getting the max date from it, and then extracting the rows matching that max date.
A materialized view is cached and only regenerates if the underlying data changes but is not dropped and recreated.

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Presumably you have an index on an id column. Perhaps a query like this will let the optimizer/planner bypass scanning the table with the older data:
select * from table1
qualify first_value(date) over (order by id) >
    (select first_value(dt) over (order by id) from table2 limit 1)
union all
select * from table2
qualify first_value(date) over (order by id) >
    (select first_value(dt) over (order by id) from table1 limit 1);


Procedural declarations may work for you. See BigQuery documentation
DECLARE md1 DATE; --for maxdate1
DECLARE md2 DATE; --for maxdate2

--create tables 1 and 2 for the purposes of this example.
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 AS (
    SELECT
      "abc" as field1,
      CAST("2023-01-01" as date) AS date
  );

CREATE TEMP TABLE table2 AS (
    SELECT
      "abc" as field1,
      CAST("2023-01-02" AS date) AS date
  );

SET md1 = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table1);
SET md2 = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table2);

CASE
  WHEN
    (SELECT md1 > md2) THEN SELECT "table1 selected" AS source, * FROM table1;
  ELSE
    SELECT "table 2 selected" AS source, * FROM table2;
END CASE;

